# Множественное ветвление в зависимости от свойства

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь улучшить свой код и сделать его изящнее, а не громоздким.

Задача: есть множество (~30) массивов из bool'ов, которые являются свойствами для binding'а такого же множества групп RadioButton'ов в окне WPF. Это уже реализовано и работает. Теперь нужно в каждой из групп сделать маленькую кнопочку, снимающую любые выборы RadioButton'ов.

Прорабатывал два варианта.
Первый:

```
    void Reset(string propertyName = "")
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "RelationTypeMap": RelationTypeMap = Enumerable.Repeat(false, relationTypeSize).ToArray(); break;
            case "SexMap": SexMap = Enumerable.Repeat(false, twoVariants).ToArray(); break;
            case "MarriageStateMap": MarriageStateMap = Enumerable.Repeat(false, marriageStateSize).ToArray(); break;
            //  остальные массивы
            default: /* нужно выполнить ВСЕ пункты */ break;
        }
    }
```

Недостаток первого способа: не знаю, как в ветке default обработать все пункты, не перечисляя повторно порядка 30 строк.

Поэтому попробовал второй вариант:

```
    void Reset(string propertyName = "")
    {
        var all = propertyName == "";
        if (propertyName == "RelationTypeMap" || all) RelationTypeMap = Enumerable.Repeat(false, relationTypeSize).ToArray();
        if (propertyName == "SexMap" || all) SexMap = Enumerable.Repeat(false, twoVariants).ToArray(); 
        if (propertyName == "MarriageStateMap" || all) MarriageStateMap = Enumerable.Repeat(false, marriageStateSize).ToArray();
            //  остальные массивы
    }
```

Так, конечно, работает, но код очевидно плох выполнением всех if-ов.

Третий вариант - объединить все массивы в двухмерный ступенчатый массив - по ряду причин не вариант.

Прошу совета: как бы вы организовали такой код? Чувствую, что можно как-то изящнее.

Comment: Возможно в метод `Reset` вместо `propertyName` лучше передавать сразу массив, с которым нужно произвести манипуляции и `repeatSize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, можно завести словарик и писать туда ваши массивы. Что то типа такого

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, bool[]> _dict = new Dictionary<string, bool[]>();

    public bool[] Property1
    {
        get => Get();       
        set => Set(value);
    }

    public bool[] Property2
    {
        get => Get();
        set => Set(value);
    }   

    public void Reset(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (propertyName == null)
            foreach (var k in _dict.Keys.ToArray())
            Reset(k);
        else if (_dict.ContainsKey(propertyName))       
            _dict[propertyName] =  Enumerable.Repeat(false, _dict[propertyName].Length).ToArray();       
    }

    private void Set(bool[] value, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {       
        _dict.Add(caller, value);       
    }

    private bool[] Get([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {   
        if(caller == null) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(caller));
        if (!_dict.ContainsKey(caller)) _dict.Add(caller, new bool[0]);
        return _dict[caller];       
    }

}
```

Проверка

```
var mycl = new MyClass();

mycl.Property1 = new bool[] { true, true };
foreach (var b in mycl.Property1) Console.WriteLine(b);
mycl.Reset(nameof(MyClass.Property1));
foreach (var b in mycl.Property1) Console.WriteLine(b);

Console.WriteLine("-----");

mycl.Property2 = new bool[] {true, true};   
foreach(var b in mycl.Property2) Console.WriteLine(b);  
mycl.Reset();   
foreach(var b in mycl.Property2) Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
True
True
False
False
-----
True
True
False
False
```